# How to find the encryption key of a shift cipher?

Tags: java, encryption

So i got an assignment and i need to decrypt a string that was encrypted with a certain key in a shift cipher. So my flow of thought was to find the most common letter in the string and find the key from that because the most common letter is E and when i will get the key i will decrypt the text (just basically each letter in the string that isn't a space - the key. Now i faced a few difficulties:

1. I want my program to work for every key so I don't know if the most common letter is after or before E(in the ASCII chart) So i can't just substrate E and get the answer and i can't figure out what math things i need to do to make it work.
2. Also when i found the key i don't know how to make like for example `A` go back to `Y`, like doing the circle (but i think i know maybe how i think with the `%` operator)

Anyway anyone that could help is much appreciated and i'm not allowed for really advanced commands. Also all letters in the String are caps and the cipher is a simple shift cipher.

Comment: what kind of cipher are we talking about here? Simple shift cipher or something more complicated?

Comment: Simple cipher the one you shift letter forward

Comment: I can add what i already did but i feel it wont metter

Comment: If it is a simple shift cypher, a Caesar cypher, then there are only 26 possibilities.  Try them all and see which one is right.

Comment: I know which key is right and i already know the answer ,i am trying to build an algorithm that would work for any key

Comment: @DavidBarishav Please use the `@` to reply to others, otherwise they won't get a notification. More here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: You basically want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986080/shift-cipher-wont-shift-numbers-changes-them-to-capital-letters-and-then-doesn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are trying to solve a caesar (or shift) cipher - for simplicity sake.  The principles involved should be applicable to other ciphers as well though.

You indicated that you wanted to find the most common character.  This doesn't really help you in all cases because that letter can become any of the other letters.  However you could do a letter frequency attack using this...This is only really effective with very long strings however...

Probably the easiest way to solve such a problem is brute forcing the solution.  Since there are only a very few number of solutions, brute force can be very effective.  There are 26 letters in the alphabet, so we can shift 0-25.  That means there are only 25 potential strings to check.

Finding these strings is relatively trivial.  Use a loop in the range 1-25.  Now, just convert each character in your string to numbers 0-25 [A=0, B=1 ... Z= 25] and add the shift [1-25]. `(char_value + shift) % 26` will give you your new character value.  (You can also use ASCII character values, but I use these for the sake of understanding.

Less trivial, however, is determining which string is *most likely* the correct one.  In my opinion, the best way to do this is to use a dictionary of common words - you can read more about this type of attack here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack.  With your dictionary, you just look for the string with the highest number of known words - although it can get more complex than this.  Chances are that this will be your solution.

This will work for all cases.

---

If you *only* want to look at problems where the most common letter is shifted to `E`, the problem becomes significantly simpler.  However, in *real* examples, the most common letter in the string will not necessarily be `E`, so this strategy is less than optimal.

Find the most common letter by looping through the string, keeping a running tally of the occurances of each letter.  You can do this in a number of ways.  You could use a list of ints, a map, or pretty much anything...

From here, determine the size of shift from this letter to `E`.   For example, if `S` is the most common, the shift is 12.  E has a value of 4.  S has a value of 18.  The shift is (26-18)+4.  This can be converted to all possible letters using the remainder function ie `((26-o)+4) % 26`, where `o` is the value of the most frequent letter.  So if the most frequent letter is A=0, 26+4 % 25 = 4, which is the correct shift.

Now, you can shift all the characters as explained above.

Comment: In our work we had a clue the the word E is the most common letter in the English alphabet so i checked what is the most common letter in my String which end up being S so i think the E was shifted to S,now i want to do this for every String find the most common letter from that you can know the key and decrypte the string

Comment: OK i got everything ,that the formula i was looking for ,Can you explain me why is the Shift calculated this way?like i get that its right but not how to get it.  Edit: Ok i got it now your sifting the S forward to E So each letter would go for her place ,where i was trying to calculate the shift from E to S not from S to E